# drag drop feature in iframe chrome 72

Tags: html, google-chrome, iframe

I have an iframe in which the content is draggable and droppable. I have used this iframe in another page which autogenerates one more parent iframe. The drag-drop feature is working in all another browser except chrome 72. It is working in all other lower versions of it. this automatic Iframe has no source. When I put my own src inside this auto-generated iframe. The drag-drop feature worked.
The autogenerated Iframe is like this:

```
<iframe allow="geolocation *; microphone *; camera *" frameborder="no" height="600px" id="0660o000007CIdc" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" name="0660o000007CIdc" scrolling="no" title="DragDropTest" width="100%"></iframe>
```

and my inner iframe is

```
<iframe allow="geolocation *; microphone *; camera *" frameborder="0" height="600" id="theIframe" name="theIframe" scrolling="no" src="https://test1.officescope.com/verunasfservicetest/DragDropTest.html" title="Content" width="800"></iframe>
```

What's the issue here?

Comment: Hey Babita, just wondering, have you found out what the issue is? I'm currently blocked by this issue. My guess is: cross-origin

Comment: Hey Babita Kapoor, did you found any solution to this or any other alternative for this ?

Answer (score 0):

It was introduced with Chrome update - 72. It has been raised with Chromium team. As per the chromium team, it happens only when you have iframe inside iframe.

Please look at this - https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=936299#c19

Workaround: Run google chrome with following command - ***chrome.exe --disable-features=VizHitTestSurfaceLayer,VizHitTestDrawQuad,VizDisplayCompositor***

Try below url with above workaround and you will be able to drag and drop.

```html
 <iframe src="https://dragdropiframedemo.azurewebsites.net/Home.html" width="640" height="480">
```

Comment: Hi Shirin, welcome to stackoverflow! It would be much better If you could add some summary of what is answered in the link. Otherwise this is only a comment instead of an "answer". In addition, link might expires and got irrelevant.